# Place a video on a still picture of a monitor

Tags: compositing-nodes

I want to combine a video and a static image in Blender. The image shows a monitor and I want to place a video on its screen. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit the following site for instructions: https://www.maketecheasier.com/blender-3d-virtual-video-screens
Or, if you have Import Images as Planes add-on, you may do this in BI, too, as your video/image is mapped correctly after it's imported. It's possible to model such "a screen" and join it with CTRL+J.

To have audio, do as follows:

1. Extract audio and video from your clip to have two separate files
2. Follow the procedure given in the tutorial using the video **without** sound.
3. In VSE combine it with the extracted audio

Comment: Answers that depend solely on a link are [deleted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: ok, but what about video with sound? I do whole tutorial and my video hasn't sound (I choosed audio codec: mp3).

Comment: Use an **audio** video then.

Comment: What You mean? I have video which has audio.